# JSON modelbinding using JQuery $.ajax without setting traditional to true

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using Jquery 1.6.1 and JQuery UI sortable in an application and noticed that the JSON model binding stopped working. I have to set the "traditional" parameter of $.ajax to true in order for it to work.

```
$('.tracks').sortable({
    update: function (event, ui) {
        var order = $(this).sortable('toArray');

        $.ajax({
            url: '/controller/action/',
            type: 'post',
            traditional: true, // For model binding to work
            data: { 'order': order }
        });
    }
});
```

My controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Order(string[] order)
{
    return new EmptyResult();
}
```

Apparently JQuery changed how the post variable name is formed when using an array, adding [] to the end. This change is apparently geared towards PHP and Ruby users.

Is there a simple change I can make in my current ASP.NET MVC code to make the model binding work without using the traditional way?

Comment: I'm also interested in this because I want jQuery to serialize arrays without the square brackets, without reverting to "traditional" serialization, which doesn't serialize objects very well.  It's a shame there is a single option that controls all of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nope,  but you could do something like:

```
jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;
```

in your master page (if you use them)

Comment: Or in the case of MVC3, the layout.